# No me funciona PhotoImage en mi segunda ventana en tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Lenguaje Python y usando tkinter, volvi a hacer el codigo en un nuevo archivo para evitar tanto codigo no relevante al problema, pero el problema es el mismo y no a cambiado, la segunda ventana se abre mediante un menu de barras, como pueden ver uso el mismo codigo de la imagen para la segunda ventana, pero en este solo sale una pantalla gris

```
#Importo lo basico
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

#Codigo de la segunda ventana
def abrirventana():
    segundaventana=Tk()
    segundaventana.geometry("800x600")
    segundaventana.title("Bienvenido a mi segunda ventana")
    #Imagen de la segunda ventana
    image=tk.PhotoImage(file="clickscout.gif")
    image=image.subsample(1,1)
    label=tk.Label(image=image)
    label.place(x=0,y=0,relwidth=1.0,relheight=1.0)

    segundaventana.mainloop()


#Codigo de la primera ventana
ventana=Tk()
ventana.title("ventana principal")
ventana.geometry("800x600")

#Imagen de fondo
image=tk.PhotoImage(file="garfield.gif")
image=image.subsample(1,1)
label=tk.Label(image=image)
label.place(x=0,y=0,relwidth=1.0,relheight=1.0)

#Ahora viene el menu de barras
barraMenu = Menu(ventana)
barraMenufun=Menu(ventana)   
funarchivo=Menu(barraMenu)
funarchivo.add_command(label="Abrir segunda ventana",command=abrirventana)
barraMenu.add_cascade(label="Opciones",menu=funarchivo)
ventana.config(menu=barraMenu)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: No se entiende bien la estructura del código, ¿puedes pasar todo el código seguido del intento y no en fragmentos?

Comment: Hola @JavideSs actualize el post para que sea mas entendible, cualquier cosa dime

Answer (score 0):

En tkinter se hace uso de Toplevel() cuando se requiere una nueva ventana.
Además, para crear un objeto widget es recomendable pasarle al constructor el widget padre que contendrá el actual, si no por defecto cogería "ventana" en este caso, y no queremos eso para la segunda ventana.

La solución quedaría así:

```
#Importo lo basico
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

#Codigo de la segunda ventana
def abrirventana():
    global ventana   #Necesitamos acceder a ventana para crear el Toplevel
    global image2    #Necesitamos que la imagen no se destruya al acabar la funcion

    segundaventana=Toplevel(ventana)
    segundaventana.geometry("800x600")
    segundaventana.title("Bienvenido a mi segunda ventana")
    #Imagen de la segunda ventana
    image2=tk.PhotoImage(file="clickscout.gif")
    image2=image2.subsample(1,1)
    label=tk.Label(segundaventana, image=image2)   #Le pasamos la segundaventana
    label.place(x=0,y=0,relwidth=1.0,relheight=1.0)


#Codigo de la primera ventana
ventana=Tk()
ventana.title("ventana principal")
ventana.geometry("800x600")

#Imagen de fondo
image=tk.PhotoImage(file="garfield.gif")
image=image.subsample(1,1)
label=tk.Label(ventana, image=image)    #Este widget estara en la ventana1
label.place(x=0,y=0,relwidth=1.0,relheight=1.0)

#Ahora viene el menu de barras
barraMenu = Menu(ventana)
barraMenufun=Menu(ventana)   
funarchivo=Menu(barraMenu)
funarchivo.add_command(label="Abrir segunda ventana",command=abrirventana)
barraMenu.add_cascade(label="Opciones",menu=funarchivo)
ventana.config(menu=barraMenu)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Nos hemos podido ahorrar el segundo mainloop() con Toplevel(), además de evitar cosas inesperadas.

Se ha necesitado declarar a "image2" como global porque al acabar la función la imagen se eliminaría y la "segundaventana" no podría encontrarlo.

Te sería más cómodo trabajar con programación orientada a objetos para tener más control, y limpieza si vas a crear una app grande. Suerte

Comment: Hola @JavideSs , gracias por tu respuesta completa y explicada, pero tengo un problema : al abrir la segunda ventana me sale la imagen de la primera ventana, probe haciendo un copy-paste en un nuevo archivo .py y pasa lo mismo, tambien me asegure de que el archivo clickscout.gif existia.

Comment: @wheep Es verdad disculpa :( Se me olvidó cambiar la variable al escalar la imagen. Hice: image2=image.subsample(1,1). Cuando debería ser: image2=image2.subsample(1,1). Ya esta editada la respuesta, siento las molestias.